# Обрабатывать открываемый файл в Android Java

Tags: java, android, файлы, android-intent, intent-filter

Я разрабатываю свой редактор Web-кода и хочу чтобы при нажатии на определённый файл (а именно html, js, css и txt) открывался редактор (MainActivity) и в EditText вставлялся весь текст из файла. Я знаю, что открыть можно так:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <data
           android:scheme="file"
           android:host="*"
           android:mimeType="*/*"
           android:pathPattern=".*\\.html"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Но как обрабатывать информацию с файла?

Comment: вообще не в ту сторону смотришь. манифест тут каким боком?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то у Вас должен быть сервис, который ловит сигналы конкретной функции ( к примеру, редактирование текста). И при нажатии на файл у Вас будет запрос, что можно открыть через эту программу. Т.е., клик по файлу отправляет всем программам запрос, кто может обработать, а Ваше приложение должно его принимать и обрабатывать потом.